# Pyspark: Python was not found

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm setting up a workstation for data science work. After installing Python 3.12.1 and Pyspark, when trying to run pyspark from the command line I get the message that Python is not found.  I'm new to this, so not sure why this is happening since the environment variables and paths have been set up.

Under App execution aliases I did notice two App Installers for Python: python.exe and python3.exe.  There is no python3.exe on this system so that was turned off.  Afterwards, when trying to run pyspark once again from the command line I get a message saying 'Missing Python executable 'python3', defaulting to \Python\Python312\Scripts\ for SPARK_HOME environment variable.'  No idea what to do at this point.  Python installed fine and I can run it from the command line without issue.

Comment: Are you using Windows? And have you created an environment using python?

Comment: how to install python:  https://www.python.org

Answer (score 0):

Check if your environment variable `PYSPARK_PYTHON` is set to an existing Python path. Also, in case the variable `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` is set it should have the same value as `PYSPARK_PYTHON`.

By the way, the command `pyspark` is a short shell script, you can open it as a text file and execute it line by line to identify the specific line that is causing trouble.